# NHibernate + Many-to-Many + bag + mapping table

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, bag

I have following 3 classes.

```
BusinessStream
Scheme
Bus_Stream_Scheme_Map
```

When I try to execute `transaction.Commit()` method, after `session.SaveOrUpdate()` for `BusinessStream`, I get following error,

cannot insert NULL into ("DBO"."BUS_STREAM_SCHEME_MAP"."BUS_STREAM_SCHEME_MAP_ID")

HBM Files,

BusienssStream

```
<class name="BusinessStream" table="BUS_STREAM">
<id name="Id" column="BS_ID" type="Int32" >
  <generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">BUS_STREAM_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
</id>
<property name="Name" column="Name" type="String"/>
<property name="Description" column="Description" type="String"/>
<bag name="Schemes" table="BUS_STREAM_SCHEME_MAP" lazy="false">
  <key column="BUS_STREAM_ID"></key>
  <many-to-many class="Scheme" column="SCHEME_ID"></many-to-many>
</bag>

</class>
```

Scheme

```
<class name="Scheme" table="SCHEME_DEF">
    <id name="Id">
     <column name="SCHEME_ID"/>
     <generator class="native">
          <param name="sequence">SCHEME_DEF_SEQ</param>
     </generator>
</id>
    <property name="Description" column="SCHEME_DESC" type="String"/>
</class>
```

BusinessStream_Scheme_Map

```
<class name="BusinessStreamSchemeMapping" table="BUS_STREAM_SCHEME_MAP">
<id name="Id">
  <column name="BUS_STREAM_SCHEME_MAP_ID"/>
  <generator class="native">
    <param name="sequence">BUS_STREAM_SCHEME_MAP_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
</id>
</class>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been  while since I worked with NHibernate but I remember that many-to-many relations can be mapped without a mapping entry for the association table. Is it necessary for your business logic and/or other use cases to map `BusinessStreamSchemeMapping`?

Comment: We are debating the same and seeing if we can avoid the map class/table. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but would it work if you set `BUS_STREAM_SCHEME_MAP_ID` to be an auto-incrementing field?

Comment: By design, we are using Oracle's Sequence object to generate the IDs for the primary key field. So, if I do SaveOrUpdate() on `BusinessStreamSchemeMapping` object, directly, then it works. It creates a new row in `BUS_STREAM_SCHEME_MAP` table. But somehow it doesn't do it when this class is used in a `<bag>`.